# Can one programmatically set the layout of a ListView in WinJS / Windows 8 Apps?

Tags: listview, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have a ListView template that's being used in several places and I'd like to change the layout type on the fly:

```
<div class="sorteditemslist" arial-label="sorted items" 
   data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
   data-win-options="{layout: { type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout}}"
   data-win-bind="winControl.itemDataSource: items.dataSource; winControl.iteminvoked: ItemInvoked;">
```

The default layout type is `WinJS.UI.GridLayout` but in certain cases I'd like to change this to a `ListLayout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. I was able to get this to work properly with the following code:

```
var listView = element.querySelector(".sorteditemslist").winControl;
WinJS.ui.setOptions(listView, { layout: { type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout }});
```

Also, make sure to either pull out the reference to the layout in the template, or handle both cases in code. For more info on the layouts, see the [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211833.aspx)

Comment: You can skip the setOptions call and just do : listView.layout = { type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout }; I've found this easier to debug when things go wrong.

Comment: You can also use the following syntax:
listView.layout = new WinJS.UI.ListLayout

Answer (score 0):

As @wloescher pointed out, you can use:

```
listViewElem.layout = new WinJS.UI.GridLayout({ orientation: 'horizontal', maxRows: 1 });
```